# GetValues From a Closed Workbook that meets a criteria with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

![Data Set][1]I have a macro to **GetValues from a Closed Workbook**. The macros work and gets me the data, but I am missing how to make it to get only any data with the account P 15178.
The source data contains 5 accounts but I only need to get one account. The Account Number are listed in column "A" of the source data.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub test()


GetValuesFromAClosedWorkbook "H:\VBA", "DNAV.xlsx", "DNAV", "A1:F250"


End Sub

Sub GetValuesFromAClosedWorkbook(fPath As String, _
fName As String, sName, cellRange As String)

With ActiveSheet.Range(cellRange)
    .FormulaArray = "='" & fPath & "\[" & fName & "]" _
    & sName & "'!" & cellRange
    .Value = .Value

End With

End Sub
```

Data Set:

[image]

Comment: If you want it to be a straight formula like this, then you'd have to know which cells in column A contain the product you want, and they'd have to be in contiguous rows. There are several ways to accomplish this, but I'd have to see your data set first.

Comment: Scott, my data set is as follow:

Comment: Nothing there. Please post your data set as a screenshot or a link to your workbook, if you can.

Comment: Scott I sent the image of the Data Set I am trying to pull from the closed workbook.

Comment: I forgot to add, how do i make it to paste on cell A7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can try:

```
Sub GetValuesFromClosedWorkbook(fpath as string, fname as String, _
    sname as String, cellRange as String, criteria as String)

Activesheet.AutoFilterMode = False

With  Activesheet.Range(cellRange)
    .FormulaArray = "='" & fpath & "\[" & fname & "]" & sname & "'!" & cellRange
    .Value = .Value
    .AutoFilter  Field:=1, Criteria1:= "<>" & criteria
    .Offset(1,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With

Activesheet.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Then call your sub like this:

```
GetValuesFromClosedWorkbook "H:\VBA", "DNAV.xlsx", "DNAV", "A1:F250", "P 15178"
```

Not tested, no way to test in my phone :) so i leave it to you.
Entirelybased on your screen shot.
Edit it to suit your needs.

Comment: Oops, this is old question. But just in case somebody else needs it, they can try my suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based solely the image of your dataset. If anything defers from that, you will need to tweak the code.

```
Sub test()


    GetValuesFromAClosedWorkbook "H:\VBA", "DNAV.xlsx", "DNAV", "A1:F7" 'since your product only goes to row 7, this should be good. If your data is not sorted this way all the time, you will need a whole other solution.


End Sub

Sub GetValuesFromAClosedWorkbook(fPath As String, _
fName As String, sName, cellRange As String)

With ActiveSheet.Range(cellRange).Offset(6) 'offsetting by 6 rows should get the formula starting on cell A7
    .FormulaArray = "='" & fPath & "\[" & fName & "]" _
    & sName & "'!" & cellRange
    .Value = .Value

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Scott, the data set will have 4 accounts, in this instance I want to pull only P 15178 out the 4 accounts in the entire workbook. I think I need some sort of logic in the first to say, extract only the data with the account P 15178. that where I am stuck. That's why I have the A1:F300 so it can go thru the entire data and pull only the criteria P 15178

Comment: In that case you need to change your approach. You can't use a filter like that in an straight Excel formula. In a nutshell you need these steps **1)** Open the closed workbook, **2)** Filter the data set by the product you need, **3)** copy the filtered (visible) cells onto the sheet you are working with, **4)** close the other workbook.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Let me try that and see what I get. Everything works except for pulling that one account instead of all the accounts. Thanks alot for the help.

Comment: hw about if the Columns A:A = P 15178 then pull all the data containing that account:                                          If GetValuesFromAClosedWorkbook("H:\VBA", "DNAV.xlsx", "DNAV", "A:A") = "P 15178" Then

GetValuesFromAClosedWorkbook "H:\VBA", "DNAV.xlsx", "DNAV", "A1:F250"

Comment: nope. if you really want to work in that way, and don't want to approach it they way I suggested, if your other file is in csv or text format, you can use a data connection and query to get what you want.